# Flashlight comes on for no apparent reason

Tags: samsung, 8.0-oreo, flashlight

I have a Samsung A5 running Android 8. Every so often when I pull it out of my pocket the flashlight is on.  The screen will be locked due to timeout and there is no indication that I somehow pocket dialled it.  This doesn't happen often but it is totally wierd.

I suspect that this may be caused by inadvertent use of some physical shortcut or hack that turns the flashlight on, but I have searched carefully and have not found it.

Can anyone offer some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix you up 8 comments as of now.   https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/6qmx3f/flashlight_turns_on_randomly/ its probably flashlight screen lock. In which if there isnt an option normally for your phone then you might have to find a shorcut code like the dialer codes, or look up if there is a mod for the problem of not having the option